# How do I add Gosu framework for XCode4 project?

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode4, osx-snow-leopard, libgosu

I have little to no knowledge about linking and referencing files/resources when it comes to compiled languages (I'm a Ruby programmer).

I'm trying my best using general tutorials on "how to add a framework to XCode 4 project", but I'm having a rough time trying to understand how am I supposed to do this, as everything I do fails in the end.

I've simply created a new cocoa application, went to build phases / Link Binary With Libraries and added Gosu.framework there. I didn't do anything else.

Now when I try to run the application, I get this error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Frameworks/Gosu.framework/Versions/A/Gosu
  Referenced from: /Users/ellmo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gosuTest-hkmqdspnwjepredgslldpnmuhlvx/Build/Products/Debug/gosuTest.app/Contents/MacOS/gosuTest
  Reason: image not found
```

What should I do?